# How to read integers from a file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a file that looks like this

```
2
3
1  2  3  4  5  6
```

So I need to read this file in three separate variables. For the first two I use something like this:

```
guests = int(input_file.readline())
length = int(input_file.readline())
```

But for the third line I need a list, how do I transform that to an integer, I've tried this:

```
sticks = input_file.readline()
sticks = [int(i) for i in sticks]
```

But it gives me an error: `invalid literal for int() with base 10`

Comment: `sticks.split()`?

Comment: `ticks = [int(i) for i in input_file.readline().split()]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `split()` to read multiple integers on a line

```py
sticks = [int(i) for i in sticks.split()]
```